# Use JavaScript value from jquery to javaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a value stored in a variable `Get_Current_id` in a jquery clicked function and use in a javascript `PrintContent()`. Any help would be appreciated.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#AgeGroupWiseButton').click(function()
{
    var Get_Current_id = $('#AgeGroupWiseButton').val();
});
```

**js:**

```
<script>
function PrintContent()
{

    alert(Get_Current_id );

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `var`. Otherwise, it's scoped to the current function and inaccessible outside of it.

Ideally, you should have these two functions in a closure of their own, but global variables will work too.

Comment: and if have like another jquery function and i first clicked jquery func 1 then clicked jquery function 2 then in that case which jqery func value will be store? thaanks for the andswer will accept in 9 mins.

Comment: Whichever one is called last.

Comment: okay. Acutally i don't know why but i am getting the same. will check my code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Get_Current_id` outside of the jquery event handler makes it accessible to other functions. Note that *Niet the Dark Absol*'s suggestion to just remove the `var` from inside the jquery event handler is **bad practice** as it creates an *implied* global (which can create confusing problems).

```
var Get_Current_id;

$('#AgeGroupWiseButton').click(function()
{
    Get_Current_id = $(this).val(); // no need to re-select
});

function PrintContent()
{
    alert(Get_Current_id );
}
```